# Parsing data from JSON using SQL

Tags: sql, json

When I have a data like this

```
"supportedBandCombinationList": [{"bandList": [{"eutra": {"bandEUTRA": 1, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-EUTRA": "a"}}, {"eutra": {"bandEUTRA": 3, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-EUTRA": "c"}}, {"eutra": {"bandEUTRA": 28, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-EUTRA": "a", "ca-BandwidthClassUL-EUTRA": "a"}}, {"nr": {"bandNR": 78, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-NR": "a", "ca-BandwidthClassUL-NR": "a"}}], "mrdc-Parameters": {"dynamicPowerSharingENDC": "supported", "simultaneousRxTxInterBandENDC": "supported"}, "featureSetCombination": 0}
```

How can I refer to the first bandEutra field?

This SQL trim code:

```
TRIM(jsonb_path_query(layer3::jsonb, '$[*].layers[*].layers[*].fields.pdu."UE-MRDC-Capability"."rf-ParametersMRDC"."supportedBandCombinationList"."bandList"."eutra"."bandEUTRA"')::VARCHAR,'[]') "bandeutra"`
```

Is going to get all the bandEutra fields in one column, I need them to be in different columns.

Comment: Dont use pictures. Use text of the JSON.

Comment: "supportedBandCombinationList": [{"bandList": [{"eutra": {"bandEUTRA": 1, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-EUTRA": "a"}}, {"eutra": {"bandEUTRA": 3, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-EUTRA": "c"}}, {"eutra": {"bandEUTRA": 28, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-EUTRA": "a", "ca-BandwidthClassUL-EUTRA": "a"}}, {"nr": {"bandNR": 78, "ca-BandwidthClassDL-NR": "a", "ca-BandwidthClassUL-NR": "a"}}], "mrdc-Parameters": {"dynamicPowerSharingENDC": "supported", "simultaneousRxTxInterBandENDC": "supported"}, "featureSetCombination": 0}

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Please provide working code, sample data, and examples if you'd like help.

Comment: It is a 82 pages data